# Need to convert RSS post title to NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

So I am making a calendar out of an RSS feed, where the date for the event is the title of the rss post. The code I have converts the title to a usable date and then an integer to select an image for the table cell image. But, the title is not a string it is set like this:
I am trying to pull in the title, convert it to a date, that formats it to just the day of the month, i.e. if the post title is 01232011, it will format it as a date down to just 23, then the if statements will specify which image to set for the cell, so it will be like if (dateChooser == 23) then it will set the image of the cell to Cal23.png. So I am making a table view calendar. The title of the post is essentially specifying which calendar icon to set for that cell. But I can't get it to read the @"title" properly.

```
[item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
```

I need to have @"title" be equal to an NSString to work.

Full code

```
NSString *dateStr = @"title"

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMddyyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];  

// Convert date object to desired output format
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd"];
dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];  
int dateChooser;
dateChooser = [dateStr intValue]; 
[dateFormat release];

cell.textLabel.text = dateStr;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"summary"];  

if (dateChooser == 1) {
    UIImage* theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cal1.png"];
    cell.imageView.image = theImage;
    [theImage release];
}if (dateChooser == 2) {....
```

but it @"title" isn't a string. I tested it with     NSString *dateStr = @"10012011"; which worked, an example post title in the blog I am using is 10012011

Comment: So **what is the question?** FWIW, do not release theImage, as it is autoreleased already.

Comment: FWIW, an RSS post title is very likely an NSString, isn't it?

Comment: No because if I set NSString *dateStr = @"title" it returns nothing, I need to convert @"title" to a string to use with this code

Comment: @"title" ***is*** an NSString. That is beyond any doubt. I don't get what you actually want to do and what you want to know. ***What*** returns nothing and ***what*** should ***it*** return? As I asked before, **what is the question**? What is it actually that you want to do? It is entirely unclear from your question above.

Comment: I am trying to pull in the title, convert it to a date, that formats it to just the day of the month, i.e. if the post title is 01232011, it will format it as a date down to just 23, then the if statements will specify which image to set for the cell, so it will be like if (dateChooser == 23) then it will set the image of the cell to Cal23.png. So I am making a table view calendar. The title of the post is essentially specifying which calendar icon to set for that cell.

Comment: The only thing is, when I use    
NSString *dateStr = [[stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
to specify the title to be converted, it can't convert it, and if I specify NSString *dateStr = @"title"; it doesn't do anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your title appears to be in a certain format, why don't you simply do:

```
// gets @"23" out of @"01232011"
NSString *dayOfMonthString = [title substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(2, 2)];
int dateChooser = [dayOfMonthString intValue];

cell.textLabel.text := dayOfMonthString;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = 
    [[stories objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"summary"];

// No need for a huge switch statement here, just load "cal%d.png", where %d is 
// the value of dateChooser:
cell.imageView.image = 
    [UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"cal%d.png", dateChooser]];
```

You *might* want to check if the format of the string is really `MMddyyyy` by tentatively trying to convert it to a date with *NSDateFormatter*, as you do in your code. But if this is guaranteed, there is no need to use *NSDateFormatter*.